# Rails, has_many polymorphic association to one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many, polymorphism

I would like to have one model (event) that has multiple polymorphic HABTM associations to the same user model.

It should work something like this:

> Event < ActiveRecord::Base 
>     has_many :admin_users, :through => :event_users, :source => :userable, :source_type => 'User' 
>     has_many :participating_users, :through => :event_users, :source => :userable, :source_type => 'User'
>     has_many :paid_users, :through => :event_users, :source => :userable, :source_type => 'User'
>     has_many :done_users, :through => :event_users, :source => :userable, :source_type => 'User'
> end
>   
>   class EventUser < ActiveRecord::Base 
>  
>     belongs_to :userable, :polymorphic => true
>     belongs_to :event
>   end
>   User  < ActiveRecord::Bas
>     has_many :event_users, :as => :userable
>     has_many :events, :through => :event_users
>   
> end

This almost works!! The problem is though that userable_type gets the type "User" for all diffrent associations. Is it possible to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your associations look totally wrong. First of all, if you have a 'has_many' on one side of a association, ***you have to have*** a 'belongs_to' on the other side. Secondly, I'm guessing done_user, admin_user etc inherit from User. Am i correct ?

And how different are participating_user, admin_user etc different from each other? Do you really need classes for each of these, can you make do with named scopes? 
I would suggest you simplify your data model. 
Right now your modeling looks fuzzy. Please do elaborate.

EDIT

Honestly, I think your modeling is over complicated. If I were you, given your descriptions of *_users, I would just have named scopes to retrieve that type of an user. So in effect

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_users
  has_many :users, :through => :event_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_users
  has_many :events, :through => :event_users
end
```

So now, write named scopes in your User model to retrieve *_user. 
Here's an excellent screencast on [named_scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope).

Comment: Sorry, Im a but new to rails(but I love it!). All the *_user models are just there to tell the event model if the user has paid, or if he/she is done reporting or if he/she is an administrator for the event. So basically they are exactly the same, and just telling the event model about the specific user.

Comment: Now I have corrected the models so they are almost correct, except that the userable_type is beeing set to User and not to ParticipatingUser

Comment: But if I use named_scopes does rails autmatically create the right condition for me when i use nested forms?